# Is “bien” necessary in “aussi bien ... que”?

Tags: expressions, adverbes, comparatifs

> Il est essentiel que vous ayez accès à un soutien professionnel, **aussi bien** pendant vos missions **qu**’une fois celles-ci terminées.

In this specific instance, is it possible to leave out “bien” and say:

> **aussi** pendant vos missions **qu**’une fois celles-ci terminées.

Also, how about adding “tout” and say:

> **tout aussi bien** pendant vos missions **qu**’une fois celles-ci terminées.
>
> or : **tout aussi** pendant vos missions **qu**’une fois celles-ci terminées.

It’s just that I wonder if “aussi bien ... que” might be a set expression  that does not allow for any alteration when used this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't drop *bien* and write:

> <s>aussi pendant vos missions qu’une fois celles-ci terminées</s>.

however, you can replace *aussi bien* by *tant* or *autant*:

> tant pendant vos missions qu’une fois celles-ci terminées.

Adding *tout* is possible:

> tout aussi bien pendant vos missions qu’une fois celles-ci terminées.

but doesn't change the fact you can't drop *bien*.

Comment: Using "tant" isn't the best option here. You should use "Autant". cf : Académie Française

Comment: @Aks *Autant* marking equality is likely better although both are commonly used. Can you provide a link to the Académie page related to the subject?

Comment: @Aks The Larousse http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tant/76610/difficulte is presenting a sentence using *tant* a similar way : *Tant... que. .. Dans ce tour comparatif, la symétrie de la construction doit être respectée : il traite la question **tant** du point de vue économique **que** du point de vue politique (et non *tant du point de vue économique que politique).*, also http://gabrielwyler.com/page233.html  *La comparaison par tant est aussi un mécanisme de coordination, analogue à aussi bien que et ainsi que.*